# get nested tag values from xml file using php

Tags: php, xml, dom, xml-parsing

i have an xml file in a special format how can i get nested tag value out of it for example if i want opacity, Thickness, repeat, rotation tags with value 1, 0, false, 90 respectively for first dict tag and same for the others. please point me in right direction

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pu version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>ID</key>
    <string>C0AC8773-CEE6-4A12-9C69-320A1BDB7255</string>
    <key>Items</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>opacity</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Thickness</key>
        <real>0</real>
        <key>repeat</key>
        <false/>
        <key>rotation</key>
        <real>90</real>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>opacity</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Thickness</key>
        <real>0</real>
        <key>repeat</key>
        <false/>
        <key>rotation</key>
        <real>180</real>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>opacity</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Thickness</key>
        <real>0</real>
        <key>repeat</key>
        <false/>
        <key>rotation</key>
        <real>270</real>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
</pu>
```

this is what i want

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load($path);
$array = $dom->getElementsByTagName('array');
foreach($array as $dict)
{
   foreach($dict as $key->$value)
    {
      print_r("key = ".$key." value = ".$value);//i.e. key = opacity value = 1
    }
}
```

what am i doing wrong and thanks in advance

Comment: It's a shame you don;t have better structured XML to work with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$dicts = $xpath->query("/pu/dict/array/dict");

foreach($dicts as $dict) { 
    $childNodes = $dict->childNodes;
    foreach ($childNodes as $child) {
        if ($child->nodeName !== 'key') {
            continue;
        }
        echo $child->nodeValue . " " . getNextSibling($child) . "<br>";
    }
}

function getNextSibling($node) {
    return ($node->nodeType === 3) ? $node->nextSibling->nodeValue : $node->nextSibling->nextSibling->nodeValue;
}
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WFSIM9)

Comment: That `nodeType === 3` is not fun to look at. Consider using `XML_TEXT_NODE`, `following-sibling::*[1]` or a css library that lets you do `+`.

Answer (score -1):

Here are two jobs. One you have to iterate the `dict` elements and get all `key` elements. Second get the value node for each `key` element and parse it depending on its name.

DOMXpath::evaluate() or query() can take a second argument with a context node. The Xpath expression will be relative to it.

On the root level `/pu/dict` fetches all `dict` children of the document element.

```
$result = [];
$dicts = $xpath->evaluate('/pu/dict');
foreach ($dicts as $dict) {
  $result[] = getList($xpath, $dict);
}
```

Inside the `getList()` function `key` is used to get the `key` child elements of a `dict` node.

```
function getList($xpath, $node) {
  $items = $xpath->evaluate('key', $node);
  $result = [];
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    $result[$item->nodeValue] = getValue($xpath, $item);
  }
  return $result;
}
```

The value node is the element following each `key` element. In Xpath `following-sibling::*[1]`. The value type depends on the node name. Most are just scalar values. If it is `array`, fetch the `dict` element children and call `getList()` for each of them.

```
function getValue($xpath, $node) {
  $valueNode = $xpath->evaluate('following-sibling::*[1]', $node)->item(0);
  switch ($valueNode->nodeName) {
  case 'array' : 
    $dicts = $xpath->evaluate('dict', $valueNode);
    foreach ($dicts as $dict) {
      $result[] = getList($xpath, $dict);
    }
    return $result;
  case 'true' :
    return TRUE;
  case 'false' :
    return FALSE;
  case 'real' :
    return (float)$valueNode->nodeValue;
  case 'string' :
    return $valueNode->nodeValue;
  }
}
```

Put together: https://eval.in/private/b88a430a237494

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pu version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>ID</key>
    <string>C0AC8773-CEE6-4A12-9C69-320A1BDB7255</string>
    <key>Items</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>opacity</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Thickness</key>
        <real>0</real>
        <key>repeat</key>
        <false/>
        <key>rotation</key>
        <real>90</real>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>opacity</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Thickness</key>
        <real>0</real>
        <key>repeat</key>
        <false/>
        <key>rotation</key>
        <real>180</real>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>opacity</key>
        <real>1</real>
        <key>Thickness</key>
        <real>0</real>
        <key>repeat</key>
        <false/>
        <key>rotation</key>
        <real>270</real>
      </dict>
    </array>
  </dict>
</pu>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

function getValue($xpath, $node) {
  $valueNode = $xpath->evaluate('following-sibling::*', $node)->item(0);
  switch ($valueNode->nodeName) {
  case 'array' : 
    $dicts = $xpath->evaluate('dict', $valueNode);
    foreach ($dicts as $dict) {
      $result[] = getList($xpath, $dict);
    }
    return $result;
  case 'true' :
    return TRUE;
  case 'false' :
    return FALSE;
  case 'real' :
    return (float)$valueNode->nodeValue;
  case 'string' :
    return $valueNode->nodeValue;
  }
}

function getList($xpath, $node) {
  $items = $xpath->evaluate('key', $node);
  $result = [];
  foreach ($items as $item) {
    $result[$item->nodeValue] = getValue($xpath, $item);
  }
  return $result;
}

$result = [];
$dicts = $xpath->evaluate('/pu/dict');
foreach ($dicts as $dict) {
  $result[] = getList($xpath, $dict);
}

var_dump($result);
```